# Esconder scroll de um iframe

Tags: html, iframe, rolamento

Tenho um elemento iframe no meu site porém ele ta mostrando o scroll vertical. Como posso esconder ele?

Código de exemplo:

```
<html>
<style>
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="child">
            <iframe frameborder="0"  src="http://www.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=439&boxtag=7868&sec=main"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

OBS: Já tentei utilizar o scrolling=“no” porém ele desabilita o scroll, eu não quero desabilitar, apenas esconder.

Comment: Não tem como esconder o scroll do iframe e deixar ele rolável, EXCETO se vc tiver controle sobre o HTML interno dele, se ele for do mesmo domínio. Ou então vc pode recorrer à gambiarra da resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara vc já tem uma `div` por fora do `iframe` use ele para fazer um "crop box". Tipo deixe ela ligeiramente menor que o `iframe` que está dentro apenas o suficiente para "cortar" a barra de rolagem...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Aqui não vai funcionar pq o endereço do seu `iframe` é `http` e não `https`. Então no exemplo abaixo eu usei outro referencia, apenas como exemplo.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 280px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        <iframe frameborder="0"  src="https://motherfuckingwebsite.com/" ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```